# How is the data returned to main?

Tags: c++, data-structures, return, binary-search-tree

I wrote this piece of code and it appears to work but when I re-analyze it, I wonder how the data (minimum) is returned to the main function?
Given this binary tree:

```
           17
       14      19
    12       18  20
       13          21
```

And this code:

```
struct Node {
   int data;
   Node* left;
   Node* right;
};

int min(Node* root) {
   if(root == NULL)
      return 0;
   else if(root->left == NULL)
      return root->data;
   else
      min(root->left);
}
```

The last calling to `min(Node*)` will return `root->data` but the caller has no `return` in `min(root->left)`. All the `return`s are already been skipped in the previous `min(Node*)`.

Comment: "I wrote this piece of code and it works" -> "I wrote this piece of code and it *appears to work*".

Answer (score 4):

The code has Undefined Behaviour, so it works by accident. It's illegal in C++ for control flow to reach the end of a non-`void` function without returning a value (`main` is the only exception).

Note that you should always compile your code with warnings enabled, in which case this would have been flagged by the compiler.

---

What *may* be happening is that the return value gets stored in a register (normally `eax`, I believe) by the most nested call, and since the other calls don't actually execute a `return`, they don't overwrite it. However, do note that this is pure speculation and could change with a different compiler, different compilation flags etc. *Undefined behaviour is undefined* and can never be relied upon.

Answer (score 2):

This code contains undefined behavior, so from a language-lawyer perspective, it's sheer luck that it works.

In practice, what is most likely happening (on X86 architectures) is that the `min()` function stores the result in the `eax` register.

Since the function does nothing at all after recursively invoking itself, the `eax` register is left in whatever state the called function left it, and that implicitly becomes the result of the function itself.

In short, `min(root->left);` gets compiled exactly as if it was `return min(root->left);` out of sheer luck.

**Edit**:

An additional note: Your function is written in a way that allows for something called **tail recursion**, which may or may not be coming into play here. In any case, you should never rely on that behavior anyways.

Comment: So, one of the solution is adding `return` in `min(root->left)`?

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki That's exactly what you should be doing. Personally, I would also get rid of that final else. so that all code paths  have a return statement. The official rule is "every **reachable** code path of a non-void function must lead to a valid return statement", but applying the rule to all code paths, reachable or not, is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually mean "and it [accidentally] works [on the test data I tried]?" For, to make it work, the last branch should read `else return min(root->left);` Did your compiler issued any warnings about possible control paths with no `return`?

Comment: The compiler didn't issued any warnings about this. I compiled it using this command:   `g++ file.cpp -o main`.   I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki: you should always add `-Wall` when you compile, i.e.  `g++ -Wall file.cpp -o main` - otherwise you won't get helpful compiler warnings. Try it with the code above and you will see how much time this might have saved you !

Comment: But it is actually strange that default gcc did not complain at all.